# PHP array for an SQL “IN” clause?

Tags: php, sql, clause

i am trying to search multiple roll numbers from database with html form e.g 2345,7654,8976 in a single field
now for php i am trying

```
$query = "SELECT `firstname`, `lastname`, `roll`, `board`, `city` FROM `result` WHERE 1=1";

if(isset($_POST['mroll']))
{
$mroll=$_POST['mroll'];
$query.="and roll IN ('$mroll')";
}
```

but $_POST['mroll'] will be like this => 2345,7654,8976
for sql i have to quote them like this => '2345','7654','8976'
before using it in query
please help.

Comment: Integers don't need to be quoted. You are open to SQL injections though. I'm not recommending this but `and roll IN ($mroll)` would work.

Comment: which data type is the column roll?

Comment: `explode(',', $_POST['mroll'])`

Comment: Implode with comma and use it no need to add quotes

Comment: @pieter-van-den-ham implode or explode ?

Comment: Doesn't even need to implode/explode/any PHP function, if it really is `2345,7654,8976`. Just get rid of quotes and it will work (but open the DB up to injections).

Comment: Great to see this suppose if value already available in comma separated than y u suggest explode() or if its an array as mentioned in title than just implode it. Correct me if I m wrong

Comment: @chris85 you are right

Comment: @chris85 thanks i was using quotes for $mroll now removed them and its working..

Comment: @RajdeepPaul That is incorrect, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af44d/1.

Comment: @chris85 Wooh! Learnt new thing today. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the values are integers if you unquote the variable the query will be valid. This will open you to SQL injections though. You should use a parameterized query and pass each value in as a placeholder. Try something like:

```
$query = "SELECT `firstname`, `lastname`, `roll`, `board`, `city` FROM `result` WHERE 1=1";
if(isset($_POST['mroll'])) {
     $mroll=$_POST['mroll'];
     foreach(explode(',', $mroll) as $int) {
         $placeholders .= '?, ';
         $params[] = $int; 
     }
     $placeholders = rtrim ($placeholders, ', ');
     $query .= " and roll IN ($placeholders)";
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/657610

Technically you could just change:

```
$query.="and roll IN ('$mroll')";
```

to

```
$query.="and roll IN ($mroll)";
```

highly discourage that approach though.

Your query when quoted becomes:

```
SELECT `firstname`, `lastname`, `roll`, `board`, `city` FROM `result` WHERE 1=1and IN ('2345,7654,8976')
```

which makes `2345,7654,8976` one value, not three values.